# Find Missing File Names in directory using c#

Tags: c#, regex, file

I have directory which is expected to have 21 files ranging from 0 to 20. File  ends with underscore and number between 0 - 20( it may be in format  _01 or _1) with naming conventions as below:

> > `DirectoryName_00.txt, DirectoryName_01.txt,..., DirectoryName_20.txt` 
> >     Or
> >     `DirectoryName_0.txt, DirectoryName_1.txt,..., DirectoryName_20.txt`

I wanted to find out files which are missing right now I am using below code snippet:

```
for (int pageNum = 0; pageNum <= 20; pageNum++)
{   
    //templateFiles is list of files in that directory
    string expectedTemplateName = string.Format("{0}_{1}.txt", directoryName, pageNum.ToString("00"));
    templateFiles.Any(file => file.Equals(expectedTemplateName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

But with this approach I am restricted to search file in format 00,01,02,03...20 and not able to search file in format 0,1,2,3...20.
Is there any short approach with which I can search files in both of formats(may be using RegEx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it twice,

```
for (int pageNum = 0; pageNum <= 20; pageNum++)
{   
    //templateFiles is list of files in that directory
    string expectedTemplateName1 = string.Format("{0}_{1}.txt", directoryName, pageNum.ToString());
    string expectedTemplateName2 = string.Format("{0}_{1}.txt", directoryName, pageNum.ToString("00"));
    templateFiles.Any(file => 
        (file.Equals(expectedTemplateName1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || 
        file.Equals(expectedTemplateName2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
}
```

Comment: Yes, that can be done but I was looking for short approach. With RegEx i am able to get file which ends with _0 to _ 20 but failed to find missing files between 0-20

Comment: Regex can help you find the `Matches`, but can't make your code shorter.

Comment: Regex can make the core a little bit shorter, but that's pretty irrelevant as it is harder to read and (according to my benchmark) performs much worse than the simple string comparison.

Comment: @hangy +1 you are correct, but I had not measure the performance of Regex so I could not say that doubtlessly when I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are probably not the best tool in this case, which is why I would just go with @kennyzx's straight forward approach. If you desperately want to use a regex, you could go with the following; But be aware that this is >800% slower than the direct string comparison - and not necessarily easier to understand, either.

```
for (int pageNum = 0; pageNum <= 20; pageNum++)
{   
    var regex = new Regex(string.Format(@"^{0}_(?:{1}|{1:00})\.txt$", directoryName, pageNum), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    templateFiles.Any(file => regex.IsMatch(expectedTemplateName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @hangy for this valuable information I will go with kennyzx's approach

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
var re = new Regex("_[\\d].");
var resultedFiles = templateFiles.Where(x => re.IsMatch(x));
```